# Empty session variable after the first reload

Tags: php, forms, symfony, session, constraints

I have a registration form for a user account in modal and called from my template 'base.html.twig'. I would like that if form errors exist after submit (check of constraints at the entity level), I would like my modal form to be re-displayed.

So, to do this, in my controller processing the registration, if the form is not valid, I create a session variable. Then, in my template 'base.html.twig' I check if the session variable exists. If yes, then I pass the data visibility attribute to 1 at the modal div level. And finally, in JavaScript, if this data visibility attribute is 1, I show the said div.

My problem is that, if errors are present, the form is not automatically re-displayed after the submit. I have to click the button myself to do so.

Here, in screenshots, the flow to try to make me understand better.

I click on the account creation button:

[image: Screenshot 1]

I complete the modal form by expressly encoding errors:

[image: Screenshot 2]

I submit the form:

[image: Screenshot 3]

After submission, the form is not re-displayed despite the existence of errors:

[image: Screenshot 4]

I have to click on the 'Sign up' button to display the form again :

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot 6]

This is problematic because the end-user will not know that there are errors and must then re-click on the 'Sign up' button.

Here is my code.

In my template 'base.html.twig':

```
...
      {% if app.session.get('errorFomRegistration') %}
        <div id="registrationModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-visibility='1'>
      {% else %}
        <div id="registrationModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-visibility='0'>
      {% endif %}
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Sign up</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div>
                  {% if app.session.get('errorFomRegistration') %}
                    {{ include('_messages.html.twig') }}
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
                {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\security\\SecurityController::registration', {'request': app.request})) }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
...
```

In my controller 'SecurityController.php':

```
    /**
     * User registration
     * 
     * @Route("/security/registration/{shortForm}", name="security.registration")
     *
     * @param bool $shortForm
     * @param Request $request
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $manager
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder
     * @param AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authChecker
     * @param \Swift_Mailer $mailer
     * @param UserRepository $userRepository
     * 
     * @return Response
     */
    public function registration(bool $shortForm = false, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $manager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder, 
                                  AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authChecker, \Swift_Mailer $mailer, UserRepository $userRepository): Response
    {

        $session = $this->get('session');

        $session->set('errorFomRegistration', false);
...
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted())
        {

            if ($form->isValid())
            {
...
            }
            else 
            {

                $session->set('errorFomRegistration', true);
                \dump($session->get('errorFomRegistration'));

            }

        }
...
```

And finally, in my app.js:

```
...
  // Display the login modal form if there is an autentication error
  var $registrationDiv = $('#registrationModal');

  console.log('Before display');

  if($registrationDiv.data('visibility') == '1')
  {

    console.log('Visible');

    $registrationDiv.modal('show');

  }
...
```

Anyone have an idea to get me out of this problem on which I have been trying for few weeks?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The most performant and human friendly way of handling this type of validation is to do it in-flow. If you have to consult the back-end for validation, use Ajax/XHR to perform the validation, while showing a progress indicator to the user. You will then use JavaScript to identify and visualize the form controls that need attention. You may have to rewire your flow a little, but it will be for the better.

Comment: I don't understand the value of using a session for this.  The default approach is that if isValid fails then you just put up the original form again only this time validation errors will be displayed.  Check the form example in the docs.  No need to use the session at all.

Comment: My problem is that the form is a modal which is called from another template. So, after the submit, the initial template is again displayed. However, the form is not. This is why I thought of using a session variable which would indicate that the form should be displayed again.

Answer (score 0):

I have done same thing in Laravel. You need to apply javascript click() method on the modal open button inside if condition.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest. I don't understand what I must do. When I must use the click function? Inside wich "if condition"?